# is there a way to avoid appending the domain to username in FTP?

Tags: ftp

We have a [Digisnap Pro](https://cyclapse.com/products/digisnap-pro/) which we're trying to configure to connect to a FTP server.

Testing the FTP credentials in Filezilla on a PC, the only way we can get the connection to work is if we use a username of `username@domain` - `username` by itself does not work.

The problem we have with the Digisnap Pro is that the FTP connection username field has a character limit, which prevents us from entering a username of `username@domain`.

My question is: is there a way to "mimic" the suffix of `@domain` to shorten the username field?

Comment: It appears this whole setup is closed to the outside. Why not skip authentication completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@domain` is not a FTP thing, in general. It is just part of the username syntax that *your FTP server*, specifically, insists on. As a result, there's no special way to "mimic" it: if your server says usernames look like this, then they must look like this. (Especially with such a limited client. If it can't even send a longer username – which is a pretty basic change – how would it even be able to do something more complex?)

- First look into reconfiguring the server to *not require* the @domain suffix.
- If that's not possible (e.g. if it's a shared hosting server), another option is to set up a 2nd server and e.g. an automated task to move new files from server B to server A.
- You could also try writing a simple TCP "proxy" which passes everything through to the real server, but alters the username field. (There might be existing FTP proxy software you could use.) Although this might be difficult due to the way FTP data connections work…

Comment: What we ended up doing was changing from `gallery.example.com` to `g.example.com` & `username@gallery.example.com` to `u@g.example.com`. Cheers.